# Page not found error when calling webservice method with jquery

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I have created a WebService directory in my MVC web application's root folder and created a webservice named MyService.asmx.  In this file, I created an method UpdateReadCount, which I call from javascript with below code.

```
function updateReadCount(contentID) {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/WebServices/MyService.asmx/UpdateReadCount",
        data: "{'contentID': '" + contentID + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (json) {
            //$("#" + messageView).html(json.d);
        }

    });
}
```

I am getting Page Not Found error.  This is happening at hosted page, while it works perfectly on localhost.

Comment: it might be main domain or url isssue check in webconsole

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why use a .asmx with an MVC application?  You can just do a clean controller action for this.